# Exchange on WP7 - 80072F0D

Tags: exchange-2010, certificate, certificate-authority, windows-phone-7

Last week, the self-signed certificate on our Exchange 2010 mailserver expired, so we made a new one. Everything works fine after this, except mail on Windows Phone 7. All phones are giving an error 80072f0d.

I Know you need to manually import a self-signed certificate on a Windows 7 phone, so I did this. I exported the cert as .p7b and as .cer, put them on my FTP server and installed them on the phone. I Rebooted the phone and I reconfigured the Exchange account. Same Error, 80072f0d.

Is the old, invalid, certificate still being used some way? Is there no other option? The user doesn't want to reset his phone.

Thank you very much.